# Error in OOTB Edit Form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error

- SharePoint 2010 Enterprise
- Out-of-the-Box Approval Workflow
- Error only occurs in 1 site collection on any library
- Is a host-named site collection
- Works fine on other HN site collections in Farm
- No modification has been made in InfoPath

See below error message:

[image: Edit or View Form in Modal Dialog]

ULS logs shows

> The form template failed to load. (User: DOMAIN\first.last, Form Name: Template, IP: , Request: http://site.domain.com/_layouts/WrkTaskIP.aspx?List=578d676d-0bcd-4049-9faf-857bb9d77cca&ID=3&ContentTypeId=0x01080100C9C9515DE4E24001905074F980F93160003A15057E2AF34B67B32E14B94EB7040900D6EDD18586B43441B49F373D71D6093C&IsDlg=1, Form ID: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:workflowInitAssoc:-AutoGen-2009-07-30T07:17:57:12Z:1033, Type: InfoPathLocalizedException, Exception Message: There has been an error while loading the form. 'd:SharePointListItem_RW/d:Incident File Number' has an invalid token.)

Fixes found on Google and already tried:

- IIS Reset
- Deactivate and Reactivate SC feature
- I can see the form correctly in Designer
- New tasks(not approval workflow related) in the same list display fine
- Approval workflow behaved correctly in the past according to users

Any suggestions before I delete the site collection and reconnect the database?

Comment: Does your Workflow Task content type have an added field (Incident File Number) in it?

Comment: Good observation.  That is a result of a VS solution that affected our whole farm.  It has been there a couple of years and is present in site collections that work correctly.  It would be synonymous with "Item" in a normal farm.

Comment: It sounds like the task form (which is an infopath form) doesn't have the XML to handle the custom field. All I can think you should do is retract and redeploy the VS solution.

Comment: @ErinL Where can I find the task form?  I looked for _layouts/WrkTaskIP.aspx in /14/bin/layouts and found it, but that affects the whole farm and this works everywhere else.  You mentioned XML, where would that be stored, if it became corrupt?

Comment: Also, the VS solution you mention has nothing to do with OOTB Approval Workflows or their content type.  It only renamed the title of the base Item content type.

Comment: No, definitely do not change anything in _layouts. Try this... http://www.threewill.com/updating-task-approval-form-box-sharepoint-approval-workflow/ example of adding custom fields to a workflow's task forms.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround, but I still don't know what caused it.  If I edit the workflow and have it write tasks in a "new task list", my issue is resolved.

Comment: delete the xsn file and republish the workflow.

Comment: I just deleted the xsn file for the edit task form from the _catalog/wfpub folder.  I then republished the workflow.  I have the same error in browser.  Sorry.  This is the kind of answer I expected to fix this issue.  Maybe I'm not doing it right?  Perhaps you could expound on your comment in an answer?

Comment: is this a custom edit form in Infopath?

Comment: No.  It is the edit task form on an OOTB 2010 Approval workflow. (globally published)

Comment: cool, you need to open the workflow in designer -> in the bottom right there would be a xsn files -> delete all of them -> Republish

Comment: also can you look in this as well: https://finarne.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/sharepoint-eventreceiver-afterproperties-and-date-fields/

Comment: It appears that the problem is not actually with the form.  The problem is with the task 'token' that the form references.  I have come to believe the form is correct, even though that is where the error is exhibited.  A new task list that uses the current xsn form works fine.

Comment: Ok..sorry couldn't help you :)